# About sectioning your UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm working on a tableview, which displays more than one line of text in its cell. I want to have two sections, which I've already done. But is it possible to display another array in the second section, not the same? T

Here's the code I use:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            if (section == 0) { 
            return MIN([titles count], [subtitles count]);
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do this.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) { 
        return MIN([titles count], [subtitles count]);
    }
    else {
        return MIN([titles2 count], [subtitles2 count]);
    }
}
```

Just make sure to switch arrays in all UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods.

---

But I would suggest nested arrays. It makes the code shorter, because when you have more than 10 sections your code will become long and ugly.

And with nested arrays you only have the long ugly code in viewDidLoad or whereever you initialize your array;

```
titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:titles0, titles1, nil];
subtitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:subtitles0, subtitles1, nil];
```

.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return MIN([[titles objectAtIndex:section] count], [[subtitles objectAtIndex:section]count]);
}
```

Comment: I had to change cellForRowAtIndexPath to   `if (indexPath.section == 0)
 {
  cell.textLabel.text = [titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = [subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
 else
  if (indexPath.section == 1)
  {
   cell.textLabel.text = [titles2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = [subtitles2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
 
 return cell; `                                        But now everything works fine. Thanks:)

Comment: thats what I meant with `Just make sure to switch arrays in all UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods.` :-)